# Como validar rangos de fechas con nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo una fecha de inicio y una fecha de fin.

Quisiera saber como realizar una función que valide si la fecha de hoy esta dentro de ese rango de fechas.

Comment: aver, tienes 2 fechas y quieres saber si "ahora" esta dentro de ese rango?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor tu pregunta?

Comment: Exactamente, básicamente es saber si el plan está vigente a día de hoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes intentar con el moment, utilizando una funcion que trae que se llama between

```
var moment    = require('moment');

// el moment() seria la fecha actual, igual podrias asignarle una fecha diferente a la actual moment por ejemplo('2016-06-06')

if( moment().isBetween( moment('2016-01-01'), moment('2016-12-31') ) ){
    res.json( 'la fecha de hoy esta en el rango')
}else{
    res.json( 'la fecha actual no esta en el rango')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de escribir una función, puedes utilizar estas excelentes librerias que estan bien probadas: [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) y el plugin [moment-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range):

Ademas, para obtener la fecha de hoy, tienes el objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date), que al crearlo obtienes la fecha actual.

Luego haces algo así:

```
var moment = require('moment');
require('moment-range');

// en el momento de comparar

var inicioDelCurso = new Date(2016, 3, 7), // declaras las fechas
    finDelCurso   = new Date(2016, 11, 30),
    rangoDelCurso = moment().range(inicioDelCurso, finDelCurso), // creas el rango del curso
    ahoraMismo = new Date();

// esto retorna verdadero, desde noviembre próximo retornaría falso
rangoDelCurso.contains(ahoraMismo); 

// esto retorna falso
rangoDelCurso.contains(new Date(2015, 1, 1));
```

Recuerda que debes instalar los módulos:

```
npm install moment
npm install moment-range
```